# Solarized theme for vim on raspberry pi

Tags: vim, terminal, raspberry-pi, putty

I have raspberry and I installed clear raspian. First of all I installed on it vim and configured solarized theme. My .vimrc:

```
syntax on
set smartindent
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256
colorscheme solarized
set background=dark
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set showcmd
set number
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au VimEnter * loadview
nmap <esc><esc> :q<cr>
nmap <F2> :w<cr>
```

When I connect with putty and run vim it's all okay like in screenshots. But when I run vim directly on raspberry all text is blue. Maybe I need to configure terminal colors? But I didn't find how to do it on raspberry.

Comment: With terminal problems, you should tell us more about your terminal (which one, value of `$TERM`, ...)

Comment: I have clean raspbian, just installed and upgraded. And I don't know where to look this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using external terminal `fbterm`.

Minimal configuration for solarized theme in vimrc:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256
colorscheme solarized
```

And installing `fbterm`

```
sudo apt-get install fbterm
export TERM=fbterm
```

Starting fbterm from default terminal:

```
fbterm
```

Checking how many colors are in your current terminal

```
tput colors
```

For solarized theme needed 256 colors.